# How to change a tile dynamically in Tiled? (AndEngine)

Tags: java, andengine, tiled

I want to fall down a tile on my tilemap when player walks over that specific tile after a few seconds.How would I do that?

Edit:
I'm developing a 2D platformer game...I want when player jumps on a platform,that platform fall down after a specified time.

[image]

I add a custom properties to each tile.
TMX File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="50" height="50" tilewidth="30" tileheight="30" nextobjectid="1">
<tileset firstgid="1" name="8246060_orig" tilewidth="30" tileheight="30" tilecount="495">
<image source="tile_image/8246060_orig.jpg" width="1000" height="459"/>
<tile id="41">
<properties>
<property name="spring" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
<tile id="42">
<properties>
<property name="spring" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
<tile id="43">
<properties>
<property name="spring" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
</tileset>
<tileset firstgid="496" name="26078133-tile-set-platform-for-game" tilewidth="30" tileheight="30" tilecount="120">
<image source="tile_image/26078133-tile-set-platform-for-game.jpg" width="450" height="257"/>
<tile id="38">
<properties>
<property name="winter" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
<tile id="39">
<properties>
<property name="winter" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
<tile id="40">
<properties>
<property name="winter" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
</tileset>
<layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="50" height="50">
<data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3RwRGAIAADwUARYg1q/9VQjJTAS4dhH/vP5HpJOgAAALCkoyZtOOv/W3Z0JbmHJ3Nt9Pruf/wPAAAAwJ5e255BJRAnAAA=
</data>
</layer>
```

GameScene:

```
try {
        mTmxLoader = new TMXLoader(activity.getAssets(),
                engine.getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.NEAREST, vbom);
        mTmxLoader = new TMXLoader(activity.getAssets(), engine.getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, vbom, new ITMXTilePropertiesListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTMXTileWithPropertiesCreated(final TMXTiledMap pTMXTiledMap, final TMXLayer pTMXLayer, final TMXTile pTMXTile, final TMXProperties<TMXTileProperty> pTMXTileProperties) {

                if(pTMXTileProperties.containsTMXProperty("spring", "true")) {
                final Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(??);//How do I get the coordinates of a platform
                        final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
                      Body body=PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
                        rect.setVisible(true);
                        attachChild(rect);
                        body.setUserData("spring");
                }
                else if(pTMXTileProperties.containsTMXProperty("winter", "true")){

                }
            }
        });
```

contactListener:

```
if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("spring")
                        && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")) {
                    engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.4f,
                            new ITimerCallback() {
                                public void onTimePassed(
                                        final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                                    pTimerHandler.reset();
                                    engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                                    x1.getBody().setType(
                                            BodyType.DynamicBody);
                                }
                            }));
                }
```

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to add a custom property to the tile and then check in your code if you stand on a tile with that property.

Comment: So you want to delete the tile or something? What do you want exactly?

Comment: You can f.e. make the tile body dynamic and set a velocity after a few seconds to let the tile fall down using setLinearVelocity(0, -velocityY)

Comment: @sjkm I'm new with Tiled.I've problem how to make the tile body dynamically?please help me...thanks

Comment: When you load the tmx file then you can create a dynamic body instead of the static (BodyType.StaticBody). Have a look at the Box2D manual to learn the differences of the available body types.

Comment: @sjkm I know differences of  body types but how do I get the coordinates of a tile(platform) in above code(GameScene class).`final Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(??)`...pTMXTile has not getTilex() and getTiley() methods

Comment: You have a callback "onTMXTileWithPropertiesCreated" in which you can create different kind of bodies based on the tile properties...

Answer (score 1):

use Box2D and create dynamic bodies . and when you want to delete that body(after a few seconds) just destroy its body